# Compare a small string in big string in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have to compare a small string in a string. For example, I have two columns that are A and B

```
A                   B
test_BL_pa.txt      1
test_AL_pa.txt      2 
test_BL_pa.txt      3 
test_CL_pa.txt      4
```

With input are test_BL,test_AL,test_CL. I want to get the value at column B corresponding with column A. Hence, given 
Output:

```
test_BL     4(1+3)
test_AL     2
test_CL     4
```

Could you help me for implementation it by Excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This macro does it

```
Sub UpdateStatus()

Dim row As Integer
row = 1 ' sets the starting row

Dim statisticRow As Integer
statisticRow = 1 ' sets the starting row for the results

Do While (True)

Dim currentValue As String
currentValue = Range("A" & row).Value

Dim otherValue As String

    If currentValue = "" Then
        Exit Do
    End If

Dim otherRow As Integer
otherRow = 1 ' sets the starting row where the results are


Do While (True) ' find it or add it

    otherValue = Range("F" & otherRow).Value
    Dim currentValueStatus As String

    If Left(currentValue, 7) = otherValue Then ' As expected sire, I found it. Can I eat now?

        currentValueStatus = Range("B" & row).Value
        Range("G" & otherRow).Value = Range("G" & otherRow).Value + Range("B" & row).Value

    Exit Do

    End If
    otherRow = otherRow + 1
    Loop
    row = row + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

As you can see in the image below, I had to set up the criteria in column F. Since your post shows that the 'small' string is 7 characters long and always the first 7 characters of the big string, we can use the Left() function. If this isn't always the case, use the [instr() function](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instr.php)

[image]

And after the macro is run

[image]